# Transfer data between tables using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a code which transfers data between two tables in my database, but when I do transfer it across, the order is all over the place. if there a way to order the data as it is transferred?

This is the query I am using. Both tables are identical in every way.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hf_hauls (SELECT * FROM hf_hauls_input ORDER BY trip_no ASC)");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert order of data in a table is meaningless.  If you want ordered data from a database query, you need to specify the order you want in the query.

You might as well save yourself some query overhead and simply do this:

```
INSERT INTO hf_hauls
SELECT * FROM hf_hauls_input
```

There is absolutely no need to order the values in the SELECT portion of your INSERT.

Now when querying against `hf_hauls` if you want an order then, specify it:

```
SELECT * FROM ht_hauls ORDER BY trip_no ASC
```

Comment: Mike, Thanks for the quick response. I have tried it with the ORDER BY coding, but although the data is show in hf_hauls_input in the correct order even using the coding you suggest, the data transferred into hf_hauls is not in the order I want, which is important for other queries I am running on the page.

Comment: @ee12csvt Again the order of how the rows "appear" in a table can not be relied upon.  If you want specific ordering when querying a table, you MUST specify that ordering. MySQL provides no guarantee on row ordering unless and ORDER BY clause is used. It sounds like you need to modify your page view logic to specify the order you need. Frankly, for a real-world, UI-driven application, there is rarely a time where you would query data for display without using an ORDER BY clause, even if you wanted to display data using autoincrement index order.